# Solidity : How to Use a function which is outside of a contract

Tags: solidity, smart-contract-wallets, function

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract funTesting  {

   


    function add(uint x, uint y) public pure returns(uint) {
        uint sum;
      
        x = x+10;

        sum = x + y;
        sum = sum * getValueToAdd(2);
        return sum;
    }

    function getValueToAdd(uint num) public pure returns(uint) {

        uint value = num*10;
        return value;
    }

}


//Free function
//this is the function that i want to call in my funTesting contract
function dummy(uint a) pure returns(uint) {
    uint _a = a;
    return _a;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since solc 0.7.1 Solidity has "free functions" https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.15/contracts.html#functions. Free functions have an implicit *internal* modifier, so they couldn't be used outside a contract.

You could access them like any other function in the contract.

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: ISC
pragma solidity ^0.7.1;

function bar(uint256 a, uint256 b) pure returns (uint256) {
    return a + b;
}

contract AA {
    uint256 public a;

    constructor() {
        a = 1234;
    }

    function foo() public view returns (uint256) {
        return bar(a, 1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solidity doesn't have free functions, so your question does not make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a free function in solidity without/outside a contract{}. But you can create 2 contracts and then separate the functions you want to separate.
So your code should look like something like this:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract funTesting {

function add(uint x, uint y) public pure returns(uint) {
    uint sum;
  
    x = x+10;

    sum = x + y;
    sum = sum * getValueToAdd(2);
    return sum;
}

function getValueToAdd(uint num) public pure returns(uint) {

    uint value = num*10;
    return value;
}
} //Free function //this is the function that i want to call in my funTesting contract 

contract Dummy {

 function dummy(uint a) public pure returns(uint) {
     uint _a = a; return _a; 
     }
     
}
```

And then to call those functions there are two methods actually (1) Direct Call & (2) Super Call.
There is a great video on Youtube explaining direct & super call, you definitely should check that out: https://youtu.be/lqRYnIejWMk

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Solidity doesn't have free functions. Did you mean how to call functions on other contracts?

```
contract ContractA {
    function callBFromA(
        address contractB,
        uint256 a,
        uint256 b
    ) external pure returns (uint256) {
        // This will work too IContractB(contractB).sumOnB(a, b);
        return ContractB(contractB).sumOnB(a, b);
    }
}

interface IContractB {
    function sumOnB(uint256 a, uint256 b) external pure returns (uint256);
}

contract ContractB is IContractB {
    function sumOnB(uint256 a, uint256 b) override external pure returns (uint256) {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```